# sql oracle procedure IN OUT parameter, how to execute it

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

my procedure looks like this:

```
create or replace procedure odcitaj_surovinu_zo_skladu
(
v_id_suroviny IN surovina.id_suroviny%TYPE,
odcitaj IN OUT number
)
as
begin
...//some code here 
        odcitaj:=odcitaj-22;
...//some code here 
end;
```

Procedure compiled w/o errors. I'm trying to execute it as:

```
execute odcitaj_surovinu_zo_skladu(1,200);
```

But it gives error, that '200' can't be used as target of assigment. 
So how to execute it? Does ODCITAJ even need  to be IN OUT? Cause i know that, if it was just IN , then it would act as constant and i won't be able to assign it anything

Comment: You can't assign a value to 200, so you have to declare a vaiable for that: x number; ...  execute odcitaj_surovinu_zo_skladu(1, x);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  Dmitry Bychenko said, you have to use a variable as the target of an `OUT` or `IN OUT` parameter, you can't provide a constant. Your parameter does need to be `IN OUT` since you're modifying it in the procedure. You can either use an anonymous block:

```
declare
  l_odcitaj number;
begin
  l_odcitaj := 200;
  odcitaj_surovinu_zo_skladu(1, l_odcitaj);
  -- do something with the updated value of l_odcitaj
end;
/
```

If you want to use the SQL*Plus/SQL Developer `execute` shorthand wrapper for an anonymous block [you can declare a bind variable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#i1211850) instead:

```
variable l_odcitaj number;
exec :l_odcitaj := 200;
exec odcitaj_surovinu_zo_skladu(1, :l_odcitaj);
```

Notice that the variable name has a colon in front when it is set and when the procedure is called, because it is a bind variable.

If you want you can then use that updated bind variable in other calls, or print it's post-procedure value:

```
print l_odcitaj
```

If the updated value - from `odcitaj:=odcitaj-22;` - doesn't need to be returned and is only used inside the procedure, you could declare the argument as `IN` and have a local variable which you set from the argument and then manipulate and use in the procedure.

```
create or replace procedure odcitaj_surovinu_zo_skladu
(
  v_id_suroviny IN surovina.id_suroviny%TYPE,
  v_odcitaj IN number
)
as
  l_odcitaj number;
begin
  l_odcitaj := v_odcitaj;
  ...//some code here 
  l_odcitaj:=l_odcitaj-22;
  ...//some code here 
end;
/
```

You could then call the procedure with constant values. It just depends whether the caller needs to know the modified value.

Comment: +10000000 for the SQL Developer example, i love you :*

Comment: line2: exec L_ODCITAJ :=200; gives error that L_ODCITAJ must be declared even though i executed line1

Comment: @user3263155 - oops, I said it needed the colon for both the set and the procedure call, but forgot to add it... updated. It's optional for the `print` though.

Comment: so basically when im setting that variable i must add colon in front of it , right?

Comment: @user3263155 - in front of the variable name, right, because it's a bind variable in this context. So `exec :l_odcitaj := 200;` (as the answer now says).

Comment: btw, what does it mean that variable is binded , or what is bind variable :D

Comment: @user3263155 - [A placeholder variable for a run-time value](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Bind_variable). See the [SQL*Plus reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#i1211850) too. And [more here](http://psoug.org/reference/bindvars.html).